# Reader in .NET and ResultSet in Java

Tags: java, .net, sql-server-2008, jdbc

When I read about the `reader` functionality of .NET then i came to know that we can open only one `reader` on one db connection. So it is compulsory for me to use connection pools so my application works without crashing and in this case I also can't apply singleton pattern for my connection. But now when I start to develop the same application in Java then I find that I can do many things with the same connection as well as I can also apply singleton pattern on connection. I just need to create statement object every time.

Now my questions are:

1. Why does .NET have this limitation on db connection object?
2. If Java allows this then why should we use connection pools?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do arbitrarily many things at once with a single `Connection` in Java. You *might* get away with some things, but in general a `Connection` in Java should only be used for a single thing at a time (by a single thread). That's even **more** important if transactions come into play, because they are bound to the `Connection`.

From the sound of it it looks like .NET acts exactly the same, but you were lucky with what you tried in Java.

The correct approach in Java is to use a connection pool and every time you do some business operation, grab a connection from the pool, do you database operations with that connection, then return the connection to the pool (by simply calling `.close()`, the nice thing is that you don't really need to care if the connection is from a pool or gets re-created each time you request one).

I suspect that in .NET it's very similar.

Comment: Depends on what you mean here. A `Connection` should be used from a single Thread for a unit of work, but that unit of work is perfectly capable of having multiple statements open on a single connection.

Answer (score -1):

1. Because the actual connection to the database is limited in that way. The connection object in Java just opens more database connections when needed. There is a setting that makes the connection object in .NET do the same thing, but I reccomend that you use the default mode, as it gives you better control over the resources.
2. Because the connection object in Java will get the database connections from the pool. If it would open a new connection to the database, you would see quite a performance difference whenever you use the connection object for more than one reader.

Comment: for 1: .NET connections don't ever "open more database connections when needed"; you might be referring to MARS, but I agree that it is better to leave this disabled in most cases; for 2: a SqlConnection (since tagged sql-server-2008) will also use the pool by default

Comment: @MarcGravell: For 1: Yes, that's what MARS is. It opens more connections when you use more than one command object with a single connection object. For 2: Yes, the .NET connection object naturally uses the connection pool.

Comment: Most JDBC drivers - as far as I am aware - don't open additional connections when needed (from the perspective of a single `Connection` object. Most databases support having multiple statements and/or cursors open for a single connection, and that is what JDBC drivers use.